# Azure media player play/pause event("tech-click") not triggered on click Android app

Tags: android, azure-media-services

On Android phone Azure media player doesn't raise "tech-click" event after clicking on video frame.
1) Created the azuremediaplayer using http://amp.azure.net/libs/amp/latest/azuremediaplayer.min.js
using options as below,

var myOptions = {
            techOrder: ["azureHtml5JS", "flashSS", "html5FairPlayHLS", "silverlightSS", "html5"],
            autoplay: true,
            "nativeControlsForTouch": false
             controls: true,
        };

2) registered the event 
   myPlayer.addEventListener(""tech-click"", _ampEventHandler);

3) On click _ampEventhandler is not triggered.

Comment: Facing this issue even on the browser.     
myPlayer.addEventListener(amp.eventName.click, _ampEventHandler);         not working even on browser. The other click event play,pause works

Answer (score 0):

The click event is for browsers and for mobile its touch event.

```
        var touchmoved;

        myPlayer.addEventListener("touchend", function () {

            if(touchmoved != true){
                // click action
                console.log('clicked');
                //Here the play/pause action can be triggered

            }


        }).addEventListener("touchmove", function () {
            Log('touchmove');
            touchmoved = true;

        }).addEventListener("touchstart", function () {
            Log('touchstart');
            touchmoved = false;

        });
```